# Why the remake?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-question

This this question: [What is the purpose behind "wax on, wax off" in Karate Kid?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/1376/202)

Why was the edit created that used the link to the newer remake of the Karate Kid and not the original?

Comment: I think that was me that approved that, whoops.

Comment: @TylerShads hehe **whoops** indeedly :-P

Comment: I wasn't going to name names :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because I suspect the person who made the edit made a simple mistake, and whoever reviewed the edit did not spot this.  I will correct this in a moment.

It is slightly odd, as the person who made the edit, did answer the question giving an IMDB link to the original version of the movie.  Perhaps he assumed the OP was asking about the recent remake, and did not check the youbtube clip.

Anyway, the important thing is: If you come across mistakes like this, please do submit an edit - you even get a small reputation increase for approved edits.  When you reach 1000 reputation you can edit questions and answers without needing it reviewed.